# Cloud SQL instance connectivity with Open VPN

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to explore a way to connect postgres 13 cloud sql instance with only private IP from my local windows machine ..
I am able to connect through a compute instance tied with the same subnet as a default GCP behavior..

I want it to be secure my cloud instance to be accessible only through a VPN setup.. I have a Open VPN CE installed and whitelisted the Open VPN ip in the GCP firewall rule. Still getting the error message.

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "{ip_address}" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

There are methods though to connect via private IP having enabled cloud proxy. But is there a way that i can make it happen via other VPNs.?

Comment: I wrote [that](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-sql-with-private-ip-only-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-de4ac23ce98a). Does that help you?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere., That is to use with cloud sql proxy right.?

Comment: Not only, I described how Cloud SQL proxy help to prevent ugly stuff in old fashion way (VPN/private IP)

Comment: @NishchalDinesh , Can you confirm if above proposed solution helped you to resolve issue? Else you can refer the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

- When you receive this error most of the time it is due to not having
  PostgreSQL configured to allow TCP/IP connections or at least no
  connections from your particular workstation. Here is a list of
  common causes to this problem:

> a) **postgresql.conf** is not set up to allow TCP/IP connections.
> You'll want to look at the listen_address configuration parameter.
>
> b) **postgresql.conf** is not set up to allow connections on a
> non-standard port number. To determine this look at the port
> configuration option.
>
> c) Authentication rules in PostgreSQL's access configuration file
> (**pg_hba.conf**) are not set up to allow either your user or IP
> address to connect to that database. See the
> [official-documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/client-authentication.html) for more information on setting up your
> **pg_hba.conf** properly.
>
> d) Ensure that there are no firewalls, such as iptables that are
> keeping your local system from even establishing a connection to the
> remote host. For common PostgreSQL problems and possible solutions,
> check [here](https://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql/errors.html#cannot-connect-remote).

- You have to edit the **postgresql.conf** file and change the line
  with 'listen_addresses'. This file you can find in the
  **/etc/postgresql/13/main** directory. To connect PostgreSQL server from other computers, you have change this config line in this way:

  ```
           listen_addresses = '*'
  ```
- Then you have to edit the **pg_hba.conf** file, too. In this file you
  have set, from which computers you can connect to this server and
  what method of    authentication you can use. Usually you will need
  similar line:

  ```
      host  all  all  <IP address>  md5
  ```

For detailed steps, you can check [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html).

Comment: ., How do you edit the *.conf files when we have created an sql instance which comes with GCP.?

Comment: SSH to the Compute Engine instance and in that window you can check for the mentioned file. Run the command 'ps -ef | grep postgresql' to check the files path and edit the file as mentioned in the answer. To connect psql from Compute Engine, check [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-compute-engine#debianubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Finally i had to set the cloud SQL proxy on a f1-micro VM instance having only private IP ..
Whitelisted the port 5432 on the firewall rule.

From table plus i use the private IP of the vm instance to connect to my cloud postgress instance.

Very well If somebody has other alternatives please do let me know.